# Convert mobile contacts phone numbers to international numbers

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

I am developing a PhoneGap app which the unique id of the user is his phone number.

One of the app features is to show the user all of his contact list whom are connected to the app as well.

To do so, I am sending over a JSON to my REST server and my server validate and return the list of existing users.

However, my server keeps the phone number in international format and the contact list mostly keep the phone numbers in local format.

how can I make sure I convert the phone numbers to the right international format ?

Comment: you can use Regex for this...

Comment: how regex can help me here ?  I need to know which format I need to change it to.

Answer (score 0):

A good library for **parsing/validating/formatting the numbers according to the countries/regions** and there is [sample examples and documentation](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/). and

In Android Library, [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#stripSeparators%28java.lang.String%29) that may helpful, [PhoneNumberUtils.compare](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is used regardless of the country/region, returns true if the numbers are equal

Comment: Not quite sure I understand how this will help my problem. I am validating the phone number on my server side. My problem is that the contact list keep the phone numbers in free-format. it can be local phone numbers and international. If I receive a local format, how can I know how which format I need to convert it to.